# Error in C code error: expression is not assignable

Tags: c, compiler-errors, expression, variable-assignment, cc

I'm writing a function that is suppose to print out the description of a programs execution. A function in my program uses `0` as a signal for a base-10 numeric conversion.

I would like my program to have friendly output, and tell the user if a number has been converted to base 10, instead of letting the program say the number was converted from base 0.

When I attempt to compile this code, I get an error message which says 'expression is not assignable'.

I'm compiling on command line with cc compiler

Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)

Any idea what this error means and how to correct?
Thanks.

```
void foo( int base ){

    int theBase;

    base == 0 ? theBase = 10: theBase = base;

    printf("%s%d\n", "The base is ", theBase)
}
```

error message:

`error: expression is not assignable
    base == 0 ? theBase = 10: theBase = base;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^`

Comment: If one solution is good enough for you mark it as the best response to close you question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing here is a conditionnal assignation.

Usually you can do it like that:

```
if (base == 0)
    theBase = 10;
else
    theBase = base;
```

Here you chosed to use a ternary expression. It does work a bit like an if/else structure, but it is really different.

The ternary return a value, it's not made to execute code based on a condition. No, it return a value based on a condition.

So here, you have to do:

```
theBase = (base == 0 ? 10 : base);
```

(the parenthesis are not required, but it's a lot better to avoid error).

In fact, you can make a ternary execute code, in a multiple way, like returning a function:

```
int my_function()
{
    printf("Code executed\n");
    return (10);
}

/* ... */

theBase = (base == 0 ? my_function() : base);
```

**EDIT:**

And yes you can use that code:

```
base == 0 ? (theBase = 10) : (theBase = base);
```

But it's pretty useless to use a ternary in that case, because you still have to duplicate the `theBase = X` code.

Comment: Well, I am really impressed, I learnt ternary expressions in very wrong way, thank you for this information.

Answer (score 1):

Because you need the *lvalue*, where it belongs, at the left side of the expression, like this

```
theBase = (base == 0) ? 10 : base;
```

Note how the compiler considers

```
base == 0 ? theBase = 10 : theBase
```

like the "*lvalue*" in that expression, because of operator precedence.

The [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:), is that, an operator, so you can't use it to replace an *if* statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
theBase = (base == 0 ? 10 : base);
```

instead of

```
base == 0 ? theBase = 10: theBase = base;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put parenthesis around the assignments

```
base == 0 ? (theBase = 10) : (theBase = base);
```

else priority is playing tricks on you. Even better, use the idiomatic syntax:

```
theBase = base ? base : 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not answering the question, but might be helpful for others who encountered this:
In my case I had legal assignment, like:

```
int xyz = 5;
```

I was not aware that somewhere in the included headers there was the following line:

```
#define xyz 14
```

I'm not sure why the compiler didn't shout about syntax error before this semantic one. Either way if someone is frustrated enough to reach this answer I would recommend to check if the variable name is not already defined somewhere before as a macro or similar.